# Need help with the sentence about computer which comes with a windows system

Tags: terminology

I went to a PC store this afternoon.

Here is the sentence about what I saw in the PC store.

I saw some computers come with different versions of windows, varied from windows vista to windows 8.

Now I want to rewrite it to make it look more professional but I am not sure if it is correct because I don't have knowledge about computers:

> I saw some computers with different built-in windows, varied from windows vista to windows 8.

I learned the word, built-in on Google search.

Can some PC teachers help me?

Comment: If you're going to write that sentence somewhere, I'd recommend capitalizing the two "Windows" and "Vista" for a start. Oh, and maybe using "Win" would get some of the effect that you want. It would imply that you use the word so much you just don't feel like using the full version and use its acronym instead. As a final note, I didn't put this in the answer part since the most critical thing to pay attention to here is that 'varied from' gives me an unpleasant feeling. I'm not sure what replaces it best, but you may try the gerund form.

Comment: I think this question is effectively "proofreading", but I'd say *I saw computers with [a variety of / various] pre-installed operating systems [ranging] **from** Windows Vista to Windows 8.* That's assumjng both speaker and intended audience are aware that *Vista -> Win8* represents a ***range*** (within which there's also Win7). If the fact of it being a range isn't common knowledge in the context, it would be better to say *...pre-installed operating systems **including** Windows Vista **and** Windows 8.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't say "built in", I'd say "installed" or "pre-installed". "Built in" indicates that it's part of the computer, which it really isn't.

You should say "varying" rather than "varied". Umm, I can't quote the grammar rule, but when you're giving a modifier like this, you use the -ing form of the verb. If the second part was a separate sentence, then you would use "varied".

Oh, and in this specific case, you should say "versions of Windows". They're not totally different things; they're different versions of the same thing.

So:

> I saw some computers with different versions of Windows installed, varying from Windows Vista to Windows 8.

Or:

> I saw some computers with different versions of Windows installed. They varied from Windows Vista to Windows 8.

Comment: I have to say that ***varying from*** sounds a bit "weird" to me in this context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But you wouldn't say "varied from", would you? I would think that that indicate that Visa and 8 varied from something mentioned previously.

Comment: I seriously doubt there's any "grammar rule" debarring ***varying from*** in this exact context, but it's worth noting there are only about a dozen different instances of [*different versions varying from*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22different+versions+varying+from%22) in Google Books, as compared to 267 instances of [*different versions **ranging** from*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22different+versions+varying+from%22#tbm=bks&q=%22different+versions+ranging+from%22). Personally, I'd just forget about trying to shoehorn any version of  ***vary*** into it.

Comment: You could expand "versions of Windows" to a hypernym: _I saw some computers with different operating systems installed, varying from Windows Vista to Windows 8._ (This might be especially appropriate if we saw a Linux machine there, too.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree "ranging from" would be a better word.

Comment: @j.r. True, but the original question said Windows, and if all the computers under discussion are indeed running Windows, then to say "different operating systems" could be misleading, implying that there are some with Mac or Linux or Foobar 2000 or whatever, when in fact they're all Windows.